# find token between two delimiters - discord emotes

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

i am trying to recognise discord emotes. 
They are always between two `:` and don't contain space. e.g.
`:smile:`
I know how to split strings at delimiters, but how do i only split tokens that are within exactly two `:` and contain no space?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `regex = re.compile(r'(:[a-z]+:)')`?

Comment: If you're trying to do this from a framework like `discord.py`, this likely won't  work. Standard emoji get converted to unicode before they're sent. You may recieve the character `` instead of the text `:smile:`, depending on how you get the data.

Comment: @G_M got me to the right path. The following regex worked: `regex = re.compile(r':[A-Za-z0-9]+:')` together with `regex.findall(message.content)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @G_M i found the following solution:

`regex = re.compile(r':[A-Za-z0-9]+:')
 result = regex.findall(message.content)`

Will give me a list with all the emotes within a message, independent of where they are within the message.